# Winforms Control Bound To DataRowView Changes Row Values But Not RowState

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

A simple WinForms app to learn about control data binding.  Code below from a Form named frmMain and containing TextBoxes txtFirstName and txtLastName, and a numeric up/down named nudRow.  Editing the text in the text boxes and changing the row, I notice the previous DataRow has values changed in the 'proposed' row version (eg _Tbl.Rows[3][1, DataRowVersion.Proposed]), but the RowState is still 'Unchanged'. What am I missing that would make 'proposed' become 'current' and change the RowState? The commented out 'DataSourceUpdateMode' didn't make any difference.

I'm also pretty fuzzy on why I need to keep resetting the TextBox DataBindings instead of just setting the DataRowView (_CurRow) in the numeric up/down value changed event.

**EDIT:** I thought I was pretty clear that my question was: Why didn't the RowState change?  Additionally, is there a standard pattern (validation or something) typically used to process the 'proposed' value and change the RowState?  As an aside, I was wondering why I had to rebuild the data binding instead of just changing the value of the thing that's already bound, but maybe that needs to be a separate question.

**EDIT2:** After looking at some documentation on DataRowVersion.Proposed, it looks like I should add code something like below to my numeric up/down value changed event.  Unfortunately, I can't answer my own question while the post is on hold...

```
if (_CurRow.Row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Proposed))
{
  // Do validation stuff then
  if(isValid)
  {
    _CurRow.Row.EndEdit();
  }
  else
  {
    _CurRow.Row.CancelEdit();
  }
}
```

Personally, I would validate each user input in the form input control, but I am now aware that even reverting original values in the controls would create a proposed version in the DataRow.

```
private DataRowView _CurRow = null;
private DataTable _Tbl = null;

private const string COL_NAME_ROW = "Row No.";
private const string COL_NAME_FIRST = "First Name";
private const string COL_NAME_LAST = "Last Name";

public frmMain()
{
  DataRow dr;

  InitializeComponent();
  _Tbl = new DataTable();
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_ROW, typeof(int));
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_FIRST, typeof(string));
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_LAST, typeof(string));
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 0;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Alan";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Ladd";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 1;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Boris";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Yeltsin";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 2;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Cab";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Calloway";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 3;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "David";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Letterman";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  _Tbl.AcceptChanges();

}

private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _CurRow = _Tbl.DefaultView[0];
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_FIRST); //,
  //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_LAST); //,
  //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  //this.nudRow.DataBindings.Add("Value", _Tbl, COL_NAME_ROW);
}

private void nudRow_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Previous row has modified (proposed) data here, but unchanged RowState
  _CurRow = _Tbl.DefaultView[(int)this.nudRow.Value];
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Clear();
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_FIRST); //,
    //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Clear();
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_LAST); //,
  //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the bound control causes a BeginEdit on the DataRow which should be closed with either an EndEdit or a CancelEdit.  The code below is modified with one possible solution.

```
private DataRowView _CurRow = null;
private DataTable _Tbl = null;

private const string COL_NAME_ROW = "Row No.";
private const string COL_NAME_FIRST = "First Name";
private const string COL_NAME_LAST = "Last Name";

public frmMain()
{
  DataRow dr;

  InitializeComponent();
  _Tbl = new DataTable();
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_ROW, typeof(int));
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_FIRST, typeof(string));
  _Tbl.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_LAST, typeof(string));
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 0;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Alan";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Ladd";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 1;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Boris";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Yeltsin";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 2;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "Cab";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Calloway";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  dr = _Tbl.NewRow();
  dr[COL_NAME_ROW] = 3;
  dr[COL_NAME_FIRST] = "David";
  dr[COL_NAME_LAST] = "Letterman";
  _Tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
  _Tbl.AcceptChanges();

}

private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _CurRow = _Tbl.DefaultView[0];
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_FIRST); //,
  //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_LAST); //,
  //false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  //this.nudRow.DataBindings.Add("Value", _Tbl, COL_NAME_ROW);
}

private void nudRow_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  bool? hasChanged = null;
  // Previous row has modified (proposed) data here, but unchanged
  // RowState. Need to end or cancel the BeginEdit caused by
  // editing the bound control in order to update the RowState to
  // Modified and push Proposed value to Current (EndEdit) or
  // leave the RowState Unchanged (CancelEdit)
  hasChanged = this.RowHasChanged(_CurRow.Row);
  if (!hasChanged.HasValue)
  {
    // Didn't have proposed version so no-op
  }
  else if (hasChanged.Value)
  {
    _CurRow.Row.EndEdit();
  }
  else
  {
    _CurRow.Row.CancelEdit();
  }
  _CurRow = _Tbl.DefaultView[(int)this.nudRow.Value];
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Clear();
  this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_FIRST);
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Clear();
  this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _CurRow, COL_NAME_LAST);

}

// This is necessary because reverting values still causes
// row to have proposed version, but isn't a true change
private bool RowHasChanged(DataRow DataRowObj)
{
  bool retVal = false;

  if (!DataRowObj.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Proposed)) return retVal;
  for (int ii = 0; ii < _CurRow.Row.ItemArray.Length; ii++)
  {
    if (!object.Equals(
            _CurRow.Row[ii, DataRowVersion.Current],
            _CurRow.Row[ii, DataRowVersion.Proposed]))
    {
      retVal = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!retVal.HasValue) retVal = false;
  return retVal;

}
```